# GWT requestfactory: How to catch the exception i thrown in Locator at server side?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

At client side:

```
factory.find(proxyId).fire(new Receiver<P>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess( P response )
    {
        proxy = response;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure( com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServerFailure error )
    {
        Window.alert( error.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

at server side i use an Locator like below:

```
public class myLocator extends Locator<T, String>
{
    @Injector LocatorHook hook;

    @Override
    public T find( Class<? extends T> clazz, String id )
    {
        T result = ...;
        hook.run( result );
        return result;
    }

    ....
}
```

The `hook.run()` method may throw`RunTimeException("validation exception")` there, i expect to catch the
exception at client side in `onFailure()`, however, i did catch the exception, but the message is **"Internal Server Error"**, 
not the exception i thrown in `hook.run()`:**"validation exception"**.

Any ideas to let client catch the exception i throw at server side?

---

Updation:
As Thomas said it's weird that validating objects that come fresh from data store, but i encounter a
situation that i don't know how to use service method:
 At client i get `EntityProxyId` object, through the `factory.find( proxyId ).fire(...)` i can get the entity
from datastore, but the entity may not suitable for the user to access, in this situation i need to check it at server side, but i can't find **a suitable place** to do the
validation, Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestFactory doesn't expect exceptions to be thrown by locators. Exceptions should only be thrown by service methods, and will be directed to the appropriate `Receiver` on the client-side (the one attached to the service method that threw).

Outside service methods, the only exceptions that gets routed to the client are `ReportableException`s, that can only be thrown from a `ServiceLocatorDecorator`'s `report()` methods. That means you could hook your own `ServiceLocatorDecorator` that catches exceptions from your locators and `report()`s them.

---

That said, validating objects that come fresh from your data store seems weird. You might want to provide a `ServiceLocatorDecorator` that overrides `validate()` (that'll validate the objects after the changes coming from the client have been applied). The errors will go back to the client in the `Receiver`'s `onConstraintViolations`, and the `RequestContext` will be *unfrozen* so you can further edit your proxies and `fire()` again.

Comment: HI Thomas, thanks for your quick and detail answer, i update my question, please see above.

Comment: Can't your locator simply return `null` then?

Comment: Hi Thomas, i try your solution, catch the exception in `ServiceLayerLocator` and report the exception, i got the exception i needed at client side by overriding  `onFailure`, Thank you so much!